# ASP.NET Convert TaskScheduler to WebJobs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-webjobs

I run a script every hour that handles automated emails from my site.  If they don't respond back about attendance it will remind them to do so.  Currently I have a script at **domain.com/Scheduler** which will go and run something like this:

```
 List<Response> toEmail = db.Response.Where(r => r.Event.Date <= days10 && r.Event.Date >= DateTime.Now && r.Answer == 0 && (r.Reminder1 == 0 || r.Reminder2 == 0)).ToList();
```

From there I will go through and email all the users which require emails.

Is there a way to make this a webjob? I don't fully understand the concept of webjobs. Am I doing it the best way already?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can definitely do this kind of jobs as webjobs.
Webjob is ideal for all sort of jobs that you want to run on a background thread (or other long running tasks that you wish).

They will run on the same VM as your website that is hosted in Azure...

the following file types are accepted runnable scrips be be used as webjobs:
exe, cmd, sh, php, py, js ...

If you can make this code that you have an .exe file then you can put it on your azure website as a webjob.

So your app will be as simple as this:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SendEmails();
        }

        public static void SendEmails()
        {
            List<Response> toEmail = db.Response.Where(r => r.Event.Date <= days10 && r.Event.Date >= DateTime.Now && r.Answer == 0 && (r.Reminder1 == 0 || r.Reminder2 == 0)).ToList(); 
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

WebJobs are invoked in two different ways, either they are triggered or they are continuously running. Triggered jobs happen on a schedule or when some event happens and Continuous jobs basically run a while loop.

Comment: Having worked with similar tasks, I find it much better to let the Azure WebJob scheduler invoke the method every X minutes, as opposed to have them running continuously, only because if the continuous job fails, it doesn't always start up immediately again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expose your triggered WebJob to the Azure Dashboard. You need to use the WebJobs SDK.

Here's an example of a WebJob that is triggered using Azure Scheduler and logs to the Azure Dashboard. You can set the schedule to run as you wish.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var config = new JobHostConfiguration("Insert Azure Storage Connection String");
        var host = new JobHost(config);
        host.Start();
        host.Call(typeof(Program).GetMethod("ScheduleNotifications"));
        host.Stop();
    }

    [NoAutomaticTrigger]
    public static void ScheduleNotifications()
    {
        //Code to schedule notifications/emails
        List<Response> toEmail = db.Response.Where(r => r.Event.Date <= days10 && r.Event.Date >= DateTime.Now && r.Answer == 0 && (r.Reminder1 == 0 || r.Reminder2 == 0)).ToList();
        //...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.